# Reading data from a table (newbie MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, cascadingdropdown

I realize the newbieness of this question, but google searches are not helping me.

I've created an MS Access database and am trying to automatically update a cell in a row when another cell is updated with data from a drop-down menu. I've created a sub "afterupdate" for the text box in the form, and can simply create a "select case" to update the cell based on what value is entered.

However, the Select Case would be very long, and I already have the list of values populated in another table in the database. Is there a way to set the value of the new cell to whatever the corresponding value is?

Example:

Table 1:

**Mode --- Time**

A --------- 1:00

B --------- 2:00

C --------- 4:00

So, in my form, when I select "A" for one cell, another cell would automatically update with the information "1:00". Again, "Select Case" works, I am wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: Do you wish to do this in the form, or in the table?

Comment: Right now, I can update the value in the form, and the table is updated. The table I am trying to update is not the one with the "mode, time" data.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this in a form, lets try

- Create a form with a combo box called
  **cmbMode**.
- On the **Properties/Data** change
  **Row Source** to **SELECT * FROM tblModes**.
- On the **Properties/Format** change
  **Column Count** to 2.
- On the **Propeties/Format** change
  **Column Widths** to 3,0
- Create a Text box called **txtTime**.
- On the **Properties/Data** change
  **Control Source** to =[cmbMode].[Column] (1).

That should auto update on change.

**EDIT**

*Just as an after thought, this will not update values to a table, as the text box will not be bound to a field.*

You could change the combo box  AFTER_UPDATE event to use (if the textbox is bound to the *TIME* field) to use

```
Time.Value = cmbMode.Column(1)
```